# I found the title of my reference is not in italic, and the surname is after the forename

Tags: bibliographies

I used the Harvard style reference. I don't know why the title of book is in italic, but the title of the article is not. Besides, how can I put the surname before the forename? Do I have to cite every item and thus they can appear in the reference? How to add editors to the reference when referencing the book? Thanks so much. I am quite a beginner.

Here is the bibliography code.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Brockwell1,
author      = {Brockweill, P.J. and Gani, J. and Resnick, S.I.},
year        = {1982},
title       = {Birth, immigration and catastrophe process},
journal     = {Advances in Applied Probability},
volume      = {14},
pages       = {709-731},
}

@article{Brockwell2,
author      = {Brockweill, P.J.},
year        = {1986},
title       = {The extinction time of a general birth and death process with catastrophes},
journal     = {Journal of Applied Probability},
volume      = {23},
pages       = {851-858},
}

@book{Catastrophemodel,
author = {Patel, C.C.},
title = {Catastrophe modeling: a new approach to managing risk},
publisher = {Springer},
year = 2005,
}

@article{Pakes,
author      = {Pakes, A.G. and Trajstman, A.C. and Brockwell, P.J.},
year        = {1979},
title       = {A stochastic model for a replicating population subjected to mass emigration due to population pressure},
journal     = {Mathematical Biosciences},
volume      = {45},
number      = {1},
pages       = {137-157},
}
\end{filecontents}
```

and the main codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{filecontents}     
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Based on a birth-death process, a catastrophe process, in addition, involves catastrophes and emigrations, leading to the decline or growth of the populations subject to those factors. In past decades, the interest in developing and analysing the catastrophe process has been engaged, and emphasis and focus have been placed on mathematical models for that subject, especially the semi-stochastic models, i.e. models with deterministic growth and random catastrophes. For example, \citet{Pakes} proposed a semi-stochastic model which showed the expected time to extinction approaches $\infty$ as the initial size of the population approaches 0.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've already posted several questions but, so far at least, do not appear to have "accepted" any of the answers. Please consider expressing your appreciation for the most useful answers to each question by accepting them.

Answer (score 4):

The rendering of the titles of books (for entries of type `@book`) and the names of journals (for entries of type `@article`) in italics is determined by the bibliography style you employ -- here: `plainnat`.

As you've noticed, the `plainnat` style places given names *before* surnames. If you want the surname to always precede the given name(s) for all authors, try the `apalike` style. If you only want the first author's name to be listed as `surname, firstname` and all other authors' names as `firstname surname`, try the style `chicago`. By the way, each time you switch bibliography styles, you *must* run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Every time you `\cite` a piece, it will be added to the bibliography (assuming, of course, that the entry exists in the bib file). If you do not want to cite a piece but still want it to show up in the bibliography, use the command `\nocite`.

*Please* familiarize yourself with the basics of BibTeX -- the investment is well worth it. The command "texdoc btxdoc" issued in a command window will bring up a 16-page document called "BibTeXing". It will tell you a lot about which entry types require or recognize various field types.

Comment: That's so useful! Thx! I did what as u said, and the surnames are all before the surnames, but I still don't know how to make the titles of the articles in italic. I will try to understand the Bibtex.

Comment: @CharlesYan - why would you want to typeset the titles of the articles in italics?

Comment: 'coz when I learned the Harvard style, I was taught to let the titles be italics......This is my dissertation, so I am not sure whether it is okay that the titles are not in italics. U think it doesn't matter, right?

Comment: @CharlesYan - "harvard style" generally refers to the form of the *citation callouts*, and it is frequently called "authoryear style". The appearance of the references is independent of the citation callout style. Regarding the appearance of the references: You must go with whatever your university requires. Do check, though, whether your university requires article titles to be italicized -- it would be a most unusual stylistic requirement.

Comment: Okay, I will ask my supervisor tomorrow! Can I ask another question? I am typing the appendix part, and how can I print the R source code in Latex?

Comment: @CharlesYan - You may of course ask another question... However, you really should do so via a new posting -- ideally with a real MWE.

Comment: Okay, I will post now! Looking forward to ur help!!!